# How to install Magento 2 Order Tracking

Tags: magento2, extensions

I want to install this extension on magento 2 : https://github.com/landofcoder/MAGENTO-2-ORDER-TRACKING i readed the guide but it does'nt appear please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your registration.php file to your question?

Comment: i don't have registration.php because in the gide there is no such file : https://blog.landofcoder.com/magento-2-install-extension/

Comment: have you downloaded the extension ?

Comment: Did you purchased the extension? Its a paid extension.

Comment: https://github.com/landofcoder/MAGENTO-2-ORDER-TRACKING